# Can Chromecast cast video directly from an Android Phone's Camera Live?

Tags: android, google-cast

I am completely new to developing for both Android and Chromecast and figured I would go to the source to ask if this functionality is possible before investing the time in attempting to create it myself. (although I would be interested in doing so assuming it is possible)

Is it currently possible to cast live video directly from an android phone's camera to the chromecast dongle?  The inspiration for this concept comes from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpMTkr_aiYU).  This video shows a very inexpensive way to turn a cell phone's camera into a digital microscope.  In the video they mention its use in the classroom as an inexpensive option for underfunded schools.  I wanted to think of ways to be able to not only capture the images, but be able to project this image live and in real time which made me think of chromecast.  If one could connect to the chromecast and manipulate the camera's zoom and project the video in real time this would be a very useful addition to the classroom.

So, does the chromecast api currently support live streaming from a camera device itself or is it limited to pre-encoded video streams?

Comment: Hi.Did you find the answer?